# TinyMCE with multiple jQuery dialogs crashed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have encountered some strange issue. I even don't know, is the problem in jQuery or in tinyMCE.
Below is the simple code that reproduces it.

The substance of the issue: when we have more than one of jquery dialog boxes, and a tinymce instance in one of them, then, when the second dialog gets focus, tinymce gets stuck and its iframe becomes empty.

1. type some text in tinymce editor area (to see when it disappears)
2. click on the titlebar of dialog 1 (tinymce loses control, jquery gets it)
3. click to the titlebar of dialog 2 or its input area (the problem it is)
   After it, the editor is not working, a try to tinymce.remove(0) gets error, successfully removes editor instance from list, but leaves the visual on the screen.

latest jQuery and tinyMCE
FireFox 29.01, Opera 12.17, MSIE 9, Safari 5.1.7 // Win7

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes    /redmond/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var dlg1 = $("<div>")
                    .attr('id', 'dlg1')
                    .append($("<textarea>").width('100%').height(200))
                    .dialog({
                        title: 'Dialog 1',
                        width: 600,
                        height: 400,
                        position: [ 50, 50 ]
                    });

                var dlg2 = $("<div>")
                    .attr('id', 'dlg2')
                    .append($("<input>").attr('type', 'text'))
                    .dialog({ title: 'Dialog 2' });

                dlg1.children('textarea').tinymce({ mode: 'none' });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Is there any versions what to do with this?

WBW,
  Anton

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

jQuery UI dialog widget does not use z-index. It moves dialogs to the top by moving all visible elements after widget to the above of it, making the widget last element of html. (In older versions of jQuery UI appendTo('body') was used). When iframe element has reattached to document, it caused to reload iframe content, that breaks tinyMCE bindings.

This simple workaround is not general, it is guaranteed to work in my case only.
But may be helpful as an example if somebody has a same problem

```
jQuery.ui.dialog.prototype._moveToTop = function(event, silent) {
    var move = (this.element.css('z-index') != 1000);
    $('.ui-dialog:visible').not(this.widget()).css('z-index', 'auto');
    this.widget().css('z-index', 1000);
    if(move && !silent) {
        this._trigger('focus', event);
    }
    return move;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight varation of AJG, but I was having trouble with the dialogs then popping behind modals.  This worked well for me with multiple dialogs and tinymce editors.

Edit: TinyMCE version 4.1.5 and jQuery version 1.9.1

```
jQuery.ui.dialog.prototype._moveToTop = function(event, silent) {
    var move = (this.element.css('z-index') != 1000);
    $('.ui-dialog:visible').not(this.widget()).css('z-index', '200');
    this.widget().css('z-index', 1000);
    if(move && !silent) {
        this._trigger('focus', event);
    }
    return move;
}
```